# Search by value in a JSON multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I know there are many similar questions on here but so far haven't been able to find one that answers this.
I have a JSON array, the first part of which looks like this...

```
{
  "links": {
    "self": "https://xxxx.uk/api/index.php/v1/users",
    "next": "https://xxxx.uk/api/index.php/v1/users?page%5Boffset%5D=20&page%5Blimit%5D=20",
    "last": "https://xxxx.uk/api/index.php/v1/users?page%5Boffset%5D=40&page%5Blimit%5D=20"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "users",
      "id": "585",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 585,
        "name": "Aalan xxx",
        "username": "xxx@h1.co.uk",
        "email": "xxx@h1.co.uk",
        "block": 0,
        "sendEmail": 0,
        "registerDate": "2024-02-22 14:40:58",
        "lastvisitDate": null,
        "lastResetTime": null,
        "resetCount": 0,
        "group_count": 1,
        "group_names": "Registered"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "users",
      "id": "399",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 399,
        "name": "Adam xxx",
        "username": "x3@gmail.com",
        "email": "x3@gmail.com",
        "block": 0,
        "sendEmail": 0,
        "registerDate": "2019-08-24 11:03:48",
        "lastvisitDate": null,
        "lastResetTime": null,
        "resetCount": 0,
        "group_count": 1,
        "group_names": "Registered"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "users",
      "id": "482",
      "attributes": {
        "id": 482,
        "name": "John xxx",
        "username": "x2@hotmail.com",
        "email": "x2@hotmail.com",
        "block": 0,
        "sendEmail": 0,
        "registerDate": "2021-03-21 22:07:29",
        "lastvisitDate": "2023-01-18 10:56:45",
        "lastResetTime": "2021-04-25 08:21:58",
        "resetCount": 1,
        "group_count": 1,
        "group_names": "Registered"
      }
    }, etc
```

(There are about 50 user records and obviously I can change it into an array with json_decode and work on a standard php array.)

What I need is a way of saying

*If "email" in a user record is, say, 'x3@gmail.com' then return me the "id" from the same user record.* (Email is unique)

I'm not sure how to do this given that the fields I want are within "attributes" which is within "data"

Comment: Why is it a problem that it's nested inside `attributes`? Just use `$user['attributes']['email']` to access the email.

Comment: Thank you - that pointed me in the right direction